# How to repaint graphics after using a Keylistener?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, keylistener, repaint

So my project is to create a shoot'em up type of game and i'd like that when i press arrows my square (that will after be the spaceship) change x;y position.
We managed to have a test that the keylistener works so we're sure that the problem comes from the repaint function.

Pls help, here's our code :

Class n°1

```
import java.awt.Color; 


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Dimension; 

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Fenetre extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
Panneau pan = new Panneau();
  public Fenetre(){             
    //nom de la fenetre
    this.setTitle("Projet");
    //taille
    this.setSize(450, 600);
    //centrer la fenetre
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    //Fenetre toujours en premier plan
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    //arrêt du processus à la fermeture de la fenêtre
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //Fenetre non redimensionnable
    this.setResizable(false);
    //Couleur du fond
    this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);   

    //Instanciation d'un objet JPanel
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    JPanel tir = new JPanel();
    //On prévient notre JFrame que notre JPanel sera son content pane
    this.setContentPane(new Panneau());

    this.setVisible(true);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
  }
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
        if(c==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            int x = pan.getPosX();
            x=x+10;
            pan.setPosX(x);
            pan.repaint();
            System.out.print("Droite ");}
        if(c==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            int x = pan.getPosX();
            x=x-10;
            pan.setPosX(x);
            pan.repaint();
            System.out.print("Gauche ");}
        if(c==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            int y = pan.getPosY();
            y=y+10;
            pan.setPosY(y);
            pan.repaint();
            System.out.print("Haut ");}
        if(c==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            int y = pan.getPosY();
            y=y-10;
            pan.setPosY(y);
            pan.repaint();
            System.out.print("Bas ");}
        if(c==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
             this.setBackground(Color.CYAN);



        }


}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
         this.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);}
}





 }
```

Class n°2

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panneau extends JPanel {

  public int posX = 450/2-15;
  public int posY = 500;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(posX, posY, 30, 30);
    System.out.print("Carré ");
 }
  public int getPosX() {
    return posX;
  }
  public void setPosX(int posX) {
    this.posX = posX;
  }
  public int getPosY() {
    return posY;
  }
  public void setPosY(int posY) {
    this.posY = posY;
  }        

}
```

And our main :

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Main extends JFrame {
public static void main (String [] Args){
    Fenetre fen = new Fenetre();


}}
```

PS: We're beginners so we might well have done a awful lots of things wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
Panneau pan = new Panneau();
```

you are creating the instance of `Panneau` which is modified in the `keyPressed` method. But with

```
this.setContentPane(new Panneau());
```

you are adding a **new** instance of `Panneau` to the frame - this instance is **not** modified in the `keyPressed` method.

There are some other issues with the code, but the minimal change that is necessary to achieve the desired effect is to change this line to

```
this.setContentPane(this.pan);
```

In order to clear the background of the panel (that is, remove the previously painted rectangle) you also have to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in the first line of your `paintComponent` method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(posX, posY, 30, 30);
    System.out.print("Carré ");
}
```

Comment: Just a question, will the super.paint will enter in conflict with the missiles that we want to add after that? Because i saw that this command clean all the window and THEN add the square ?

Tahnks anyway it's working :)

Comment: When you paint the missiles **after** the call to `super.paintComponent`, then there will be no problem. Note that *everything* that you want to paint has to be painted in the `paintComponent` method (or in methods that are called from `paintComponent` and receive the same `Graphics` object). (So if you intended to call `getGraphics` anywhere: **don't do this**). Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/